# How do I convert iso to DATE without the trailing time string?

Tags: sql, date, iso

The following function returns dates in this format, "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" and all I need is just the date portion of "2021-01-01".

```
DATE_TRUNC(‘day’, timestamp)
```

Comment: Which database server?

Comment: specify RDBMS, and we'll be able to help :)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are highly product specific Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I know of no database where `DATE_TRUNC()` would return a time component.  This might be an artifact of your user interface or some other processing (say, loading the data into a `timestamp` column rather than a `date` column).

Answer (score 0):

The return value from your current call to `DATE_TRUNC` already functionally *is* the date `2021-01-01`, which in timestamp form is at midnight.  That being said, if you want to *view* as a date only, then maybe you want this:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%d", DATE_TRUNC('day', timestamp))
FROM yourTable;
```

Another trick which might work on BigQuery is to cast the timestamp to a `VARCHAR` of the right length:

```sql
SELECT CAST(DATE_TRUNC('day', timestamp) AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim!

The first one didn't work, but the second one returned 2021-01-01 00:00:00.

Any idea why that'll be the case?

Comment: What is your actual database?  Your observation is unexpected to me.